# Bucle For en python

Tags: python, recursión, scipy, iteraciones, bucle-for

Buenos dias,

El valor de `x` es una disminucion de `1.0 - 0.01` asi, el primer valor de `x=0.99`  el segundo `x=0.98` y el tercero `x=0.97`

El primer valor es `x1=1.0` 
El problema es la actualizacion de `x1` y que el bucle utilice el nuevo valor `x=0.98`

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import scipy.optimize
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

n=763.0
s=762.0
y=0.5673
b=0.0026

x=[0.99,0.98,0.97]
x1=1.0
i=1

for iteration in range(1,3):
    def l(x, x1, b,n,y,s):
        def p(x):
            return 1.0/(x*(b*n+y*np.log(x)-s*b*x))
        ds = scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(p, x, x1, args=(), n=5)
        return (ds[0]-1)
    def t(x, x1, b, n, y, s):
        x1=scipy.optimize.brentq(l, x, x1, args=(b, n, y, s))
        return x1
    x=x1
    i=i+1
    print x
```

La salida esta mal y es:

```
1.0
1.0
```

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: La salida es la esperada, tienes un ciclo que realiza dos iteraciones, en cada iteracion defines de nuevo las funciones `l`, `t` y `p` pero en ningun momento llamas a esas  funciones, solo igualas `x` a `x1` (que nunca cambia por lo que siempre vale 1.0) e incrementas en una unidad la variable `i`. Define las funciones fuera del ciclo, lo que haces no tiene sentido y es ineficiente. si las funciones son las que dan el valor a `x1` debes llamarlas, sino no haces nada. Si deseas iterar sobre los valores de la lista `x` necesitas algo como `for v in x`. La pregunta es confusa tal y como está.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, @FJSevilla los corregi y corrio bien!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has metido la definición de tus funciones dentro del for. Lo que creo que pasa es que simplemente después de las definiciones, la x toma el valor de x1 (1.0) y lo repite 2 veces.

Luego además no sé por qué motivo incrementas el valor de i dentro del bucle for, porque luego no la usas en ninguna parte.

Prueba en principio a definir las funciones fuera del bucle y llamarlas dentro, y si hacen lo que tienen que hacer, te funcionará.

Comment: Listo las declare fuera del bucle y corrio, gracias!

Comment: @SantiagoYepes Si la solución te ha valido la deberías aceptar para que la gente pueda ver que es correcta en caso de que llegue a un problema similar.

Comment: Pense que la habia aceptado, gracias @kikocorreoso ya la acepte.